# Optimizing VBA Code for highlighting duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to optimize this code. Right now it takes about 20 minutes to run and I would like to get it to as short as possible. Is there any way that this code can be optimized?

```
 Sub FoundDuplicate()

  Dim lastRow As Integer, compRow As Integer, rowNo As Integer
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("N1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For rowNo = 2 To lastRow
        For compRow = rowNo + 1 To lastRow
            If Range(Left("N", 4) & compRow) = Range(Left("N", 4) & rowNo) Then
                If Range("T" & compRow) = Range("T" & rowNo) Then
                        Range("N" & compRow & ":T" & compRow).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                        Range("N" & rowNo & ":T" & rowNo).Interior.Color = vbYellow

                End If
            End If
        Next compRow
    Next rowNo  
End Sub
```

Comment: This belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mattrew Marcante , Hi again glad that you use the code I did for you, how much rows got your excel file ?

Comment: @Dorian, Hi it has 13193 rows as of right now.

Comment: Matthew I would look into looping through the dataset, and using `Find` to check whether the current value exists in another place. You could even specify the `Find` range to not contain the current cell

Comment: Have you tried adding `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at start of your code?